# Python: Using Fabric run command to save Output to Variable

Tags: python, fabric

I am using Python 2.7 with Fabric on a Mac OS X. I noticed recently that my script is saving the variable of nodename incorrectly when I do not have a home directory on the host that I SSH into. It is because that an error shows up when I log into that host and it will save that error and the run('whatevercommand') into that variable. For example, in the below command:

```
def saveHostname():
    with settings( 
        hide('running', 'warnings'), 
        shell='/bin/bash -c'):

        date = run ('date')
        host_type = run ('uname')
        if "Linux" in host_type:
            with hide('output'):
                nodename = run('hostname -s')
                print nodename
```

It will save "nodename" as:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/yourdirectory/: No such file or directory (This is the error I get everytime I log into the machine)

hostname (This is the hostname of the host I am logging into with Python)
```

Is there anyway to ignore the errors and not save them into a variable when using the Python run command?

Answer (score 0):

One way to ignore the error is test the output of run('hostname -s') before storing it into nodename

```
with hide('output'):
    temp = run('hostname -s') 
    if "Could not chdir" not in temp:
         nodename = temp
         print nodename
    else:
         nodename = None
```

Comment: But for the hosts that have this error, I would still not be able to store just the nodename and complete my script to my other functions

Comment: Then you need to fix the error on the host machine if you want the actual hostname successfully be retrieved.